# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Getting error property of undefined (reading getProvider) while deploying the function to firebase. I still trying to figure out how to get auth instance, "when I try to do firebase.auth" it gives another error.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firebase = require("firebase/auth");
const app = require("express")();

admin.initializeApp();

const firebaseConfig = {
  ....
};
firebase.initializeAuth(firebaseConfig);
const auth = firebase.getAuth();


//Sign up route
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
   const newUser = {
     email: req.body.email,
     password: req.body.password,
     confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
     handle: req.body.handle,
   };
  firebase  
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then((data) => {
      return res
        .status(201)
        .json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
});
exports.api = https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out a way to work with this issue, I hope this helps. Its just a small correction with recent updated document.

I had to declare methods from auth library to use it.

```
const { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require("firebase/auth");
```

Also, "auth" function is no more supported, so you need to call getAuth() method.

```
const auth = getAuth();
```

And finally you also need to pass auth as function parameter to "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" method.

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUser.email, newUser.password)
```

here is the updated code.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firebase = require("firebase/app");
const { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require("firebase/auth");
const app = require("express")();

admin.initializeApp();

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();

// Sign up route
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle,
  };

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then((data) => {
      return res
         .status(201)
         .json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```